# How to count the number of similar values in a dictionary?

Tags: python

Is there a way to count the number of similar values in a dictionary,for example I have a list consisting of different users and their names, gender, age ... if I want to count the number of males in that list how to do it?

I know it might sound silly but I am new to python and I am trying to learn more about it.

This is the list if it will help:

```
user_list = [
    {'name': 'Alizom_12',
     'gender': 'f',
     'age': 34,
     'active_day': 170},
    {'name': 'Xzt4f',
     'gender': None,
     'age': None,
     'active_day': 1152},
    {'name': 'TomZ',
     'gender': 'm',
     'age': 24,
     'active_day': 15},
    {'name': 'Zxd975',
     'gender': None,
     'age': 44,
     'active_day': 752},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions for your example of counting genders:

```
n_males = sum(1 for user in user_list if user['gender'] == 'm')
print(n_males )
```

Use the counter

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter((user['gender'] for user in user_list))
print(counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like:

```py
def count_gender(lst, gender):
    count=0
    for dictionary in lst:
        if dictionary["gender"] == gender:
            count+=1
    return count
```

Then pass into it list and desired gender:

```py
number = count_gender(user_list, "m")
print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function.

```py
user_list = [
    {'name': 'Alizom_12',
     'gender': 'f',
     'age': 34,
     'active_day': 170},
    {'name': 'Xzt4f',
     'gender': None,
     'age': None,
     'active_day': 1152},
    {'name': 'TomZ',
     'gender': 'm',
     'age': 24,
     'active_day': 15},
    {'name': 'Zxd975',
     'gender': None,
     'age': 44,
     'active_day': 752},
]

print(sum(user["gender"] == "m" for user in user_list))
```

I gave a `list comprehension` in parameter to filter the users with the attribute `gender` set to `m`. You can easily create a function to make the operation more efficient.

```py
def count_by_attribute(my_list: List, attribute: str, value: Any) -> int:
    return sum(o[attribute] == value for o in my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = len([i.gender for i in user_list if i.gender == "m"])
```

Here you're calculating the len of the list generated by this sintax called `list comprehension`, that takes all the `i.gender` of all the values in your dictionary, where the gender is `"m"`

Comment: This will produce an `AttributeError` since `gender` is not an attribute of `i`.

Comment: Yes you're right, it's `i['gender']`

Answer (score 0):

that should do the trick

```
print(sum(x.get('gender') == 'm' for x in user_list))
```

the .get function Returns the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. so we just count the values m and get 1 in your example case.